# How to simulate a ‘block request url’ using webdriverjs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test where I want to check that if a request is blocked, the appropriate error message is displayed on the page. Using chrome, this can be done via Network tab > Right click on request > Block request url. However, I'm trying to automate this url blocking process and would like to know if this is possible in a WebDriverJs setup